# How do I download a pdf file in php Using Laravel PDF library?

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5.6

So this is pretty well documented in [the library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) But I cannot get it to work. Consider the following:

```
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('modules.efapreports.pdf.invoice', [
        'invoiceData'   => $this->collection,
        'organization'  => $organization,
        'invoiceNumber' => $this->formFields['invoice_number'],
        'invoiceDate'   => $this->formFields['invoice_date'],
        'dueDate'       => $this->formFields['due_date'],
        'payementTerms' => $this->formFields['payment_terms'],
        'gst'           => 1.05,
    ]);

    $pdf->save(storage_path(
        'efapinvoices/' . $this->getPath() .'/'. $this->getFileName() . $this->getExtension()
    ));

    $pdf->download(storage_path(
        'efapinvoices/' . $this->getPath() .'/'. $this->getFileName() . $this->getExtension()
    ));
```

This saves it, perfectly, but does not download it. Do I have to load the pdf file?

Comment: based on the documentation.. you need to "return" it..

Comment: Just a note on the side: It would make sense to store the storage path in an own variable. Not only to save code but also to avoid very minor and hard to debug errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return PDF::loadView('modules.efapreports.pdf.invoice', [
        'invoiceData'   => $this->collection,
        'organization'  => $organization,
        'invoiceNumber' => $this->formFields['invoice_number'],
        'invoiceDate'   => $this->formFields['invoice_date'],
        'dueDate'       => $this->formFields['due_date'],
        'payementTerms' => $this->formFields['payment_terms'],
        'gst'           => 1.05,
    ])->download();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use package dompdf to solve the problem related to pdf.
https://packagist.org/packages/dompdf/dompdf